# how to add a h1 tag with gwt

Tags: html, jquery-ui, gwt

Well the question might seem stupid but I really can't figure it out. How can you add dynamically a html heading tag to your page using the google web toolkit.

I don't want to do this for the style of the heading as I could add any style to any label, it is because I want to use the [jqueryui accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) it works with a pair of header and content panel.

How can I do this?

Comment: There's also [HeadingElement](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/index.html?overview-summary.html), which allows you to create H1-H6 elements.

Comment: How would you do that ?

Comment: Look at the answer just below, he explains how to use HeadingElement.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

---

Yes this is kinda complicated to say the least.... Here is the easiast example I can think of:

```
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.HeadingElement;

...

HeadingElement headingElement = Document.get().createHElement(1);
headingElement.setInnerText("This is a Heading1 (h1) element!");
RootPanel.get().getElement().appendChild(headingElement);
```

If you look at the other methods of the `Document.get()....` you will find methods for creating all other HTML elements too.

**Addition:**

This might be even easier:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML;
.....
HTML headingElement= new HTML();
headingElement.setHTML("<h1>This is a Heading1 (h1) element!</h1>");        
RootPanel.get().getElement().appendChild(headingElement);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that made the trick, I thought there would be an object for any HTML tag or something like that. Something like : `Header h1 = new Header("this is my header"); RootPanel.get("divid").add(h1);`

Comment: Dunno whether it's good or bad, but day by day I am growing so dependent on SO that I find it difficult to code when internet is slow, because I can't connect to SO then.

Comment: Per questioner's comment on this answer, looks like he was looking for something like @ivan-poliakov 's answer, which is much shorter and concise as such.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use HTMLPanel and specify which tag to use in the constructor:

```
HTMLPanel header = new HTMLPanel ("h1", "bla bla bla");
```

should produce

```
<h1>bla bla bla</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my Java solution:

```
InlineHTML h6_Text = InlineHTML.wrap(Document.get().createHElement(6));
h6_Text.setText("The text between <h6> and </h6>");
```